# Evil, How do I display visual range in mode-line

Tags: evil, mode-line

I'd like to see the size (number of rows and/or columns) of the visual selection in my mode-line. I use evil. How do I do that?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you can get info about a region using `M-=` (`count-words-region`) which includes row information.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether `evil` itself support this, but [spaceline](https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline) do support this feature by its segment [selection-info](https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline/blob/master/spaceline-segments.el#L187).